# syncronization problems using Pthreads

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, pthreads, ncurses

I'm working on a C project that consists of a simple game using the ncurses and pthread libs. Have to say I'm still studying and I'm already stucked into some synchronization problems, using mutexes and semaphores.
I'll try to explain how it's supposed to works cause it might helps. It follows the producter/consumer idea. A bunch of threads are generated using a structure(which contains proper values such coordinates etc). These structures are represented on the screen by a character and are moving at every interaction. All those information are stored into a buffer.
One thread has to manages and coordinates these items by accessing the buffer, reading the coordinates, and printing the items on the screen.
I've cut it mostly to make it easier to read, here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STEP 1 //value of the moving
#define M 2 // number of items
#define BUFFER_DIM 100000

void * control_func(void * arg);
void * item_func(void * arg);

typedef struct pos{//structure for the communication
        char c; // type of item
        int x; // x coord
        int y; // y coord
        int p; // object pos
        int pid; // pid of process
} pos;

typedef struct argomenti{ //structure to pass arguments
    int x; //x position
    int y; //y position
    int i; //index
} args;

//buffer and semaphores initializations
pos buffer[BUFFER_DIM]; 
int IN = 0; // occupied positions of the buffer
int OUT = 0; // avariable position of the buffer
sem_t presents, avariables; // variabili che indicano il valore del semaforo, ovvero la presenza o meno di job disponibili
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // mutex to avoid race conditions

main(){
    initscr();      
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    srand(time(NULL));
    pthread_t item_id[M], control_id;
    int i;

    sem_init(&avariables, 0, BUFFER_DIM); //initialize semaphores
    sem_init(&presents, 0, 0);

    //start threads
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
         pthread_create(&item_id[i], NULL, &item_func, &i);
    }
    pthread_create(&control_id, NULL, &control_func, NULL);
    pthread_join(control_id, NULL);

    endwin();
    return(0);
}

void * item_func(void * arg){
    pos pos_item;
    int i = *((int *)arg);
    int dx=STEP;

    pos_item.c='$';
    pos_item.p=i;
    pos_item.pid=pthread_self();
    pos_item.y=1;
    pos_item.x=rand()%80;

    sem_wait(&avariables);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    buffer[IN] = pos_item;
    IN=(IN+1)%BUFFER_DIM;
    sem_post(&presents); // increment of the semaphore
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    while(1){//code for the changes of the coords
        if(pos_item.x==80){//80 are the columns
            dx=-STEP;
            pos_item.x += dx;
            pos_item.y++;
        }else if(pos_item.x==0){
            dx=STEP;
            pos_item.x += dx;
            pos_item.y++;
        }else
            pos_item.x += dx;

        sem_wait(&avariables);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        buffer[IN] = pos_item;
        IN=(IN+1)%BUFFER_DIM;
        sem_post(&presents); // increment of the semaphore
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        usleep(100000);}
}

void * control_func(void * arg)
{
    pos item[M], read_value;
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
          item[i].x=-1;
    }

    do{
        sem_wait(&presents);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        read_value = buffer[OUT];
        OUT=(OUT+1)%BUFFER_DIM;
        sem_post(&avariables); // increment of the semaphore
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        switch(read_value.c) {
          case '$':
            if(item[read_value.p].x>=0)
                mvaddch(item[read_value.p].y,item[read_value.p].x,' ');  //delete the old position     
            item[read_value.p]=read_value; //refresh the position
            mvaddch(item[read_value.p].y,item[read_value.p].x,item[read_value.p].c); //print the item
            break;
        }
    refresh();
    }while(1);
}
```

it compiles without warnings(-lncurses -lpthread), but somehow it's not working properly. The number of the items is set on 2. Only one is permanently displayed, the other one it's like hidden most of the times, and sometimes it blinks out just for instants.
I'm assuming it's a sinchronyzation problem, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing wrong is passing `&i` to the threads.
When `pthread_create` is called, `i` contains the value you want. But by the time `item_func` has started, it may have changed. So it's likely that multiple item threads have the same value for `i`.

I can't tell if that's all.

Comment: You were right. Since I was out of ideas I've tried to fix it by using a vector with the dimension of the number of the items in which every position has the value of the index, and i passed the vector to the function. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid solution. A simpler solution, though perhaps uglier, would be to cast the number to `void *`.